# Mediaelement.js and live streaming

Tags: mediaelement.js, live-streaming

Does any one have experience using mediaelement.js for live streaming?  Does it work?  How did you embed it into your HTML?  I'm using Dacast as my streaming provider, but am not happy with the quality of service provided by JWPlayer or Flow Player.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I do with amazon cloudfront (RTMP service), since Dacast also uses same technology you are  good to go with mediaelement.js. RTMP is meant to support low latency so I doubt if you can achieve HD quality with it, well its really depends upon connection speed. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget RTMP (cloudfront or others) is supported only by the Flash player. For non-Flash browsers (such as mobiles) you should provide an alternate solution, usually using the build-in video player with http-based redirectors (m3u8 and f4m).
HTML5 doesn't officially support streaming video.